# how to position angular material(2.x +) dialog to right hand side of the screen on button click or on hover

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material2

I've started learning Angular 5 with material design, my requirement is I have to show angular material dialog
fixed to right hand side of the screen always. By default it is coming always on the center of the screen. How can import
show dialog on right hand side of the screen? Please help.

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogConfig } 
  from '@angular/material';
```

My HTML:

```html
<div class="add-contact-btn" fxFlex="10">
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">add contact</button>
</div>
```

```
openDialog(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContactsComponent, {
    width: '250px'   
  });
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed');
  });
}
```

Comment: A quick-dirty method is to set the folllwoing css: `.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper{ justify-content: flex-end !important; }`

Comment: Alternatively, you can declare a class in your `styles.css` and pass the `panelClass` property as your class' name.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar requirement for my app. I re-used your code to demonstrate how I did it. With this way I was able to show the dialog right at the position I clicked.

HTML:

```html
<div class="add-contact-btn" fxFlex="10">
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog($event)">add contact</button>
</div>
```

Script:

```js
openDialog(event): void {
  const dialogPosition: DialogPosition = {
    top: event.y + 'px',
    left: event.x + 'px'
  };

  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContactsComponent, {
    width: '250px',
    position: dialogPosition
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log('The dialog was closed');
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there any I can use a class so that I can change the position using media queries?

Comment: how can i get the position of trigger element in the same way. With your code I can see it is getting clicked cordinates. Instead I am looking for element position where it is clicked

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```js
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContactsComponent, {
  width: '250px'
  position: { right: '0'}
});
```

You can also add top: 0 etc.